# Prevent awk from converting string starting with 0 to oct

Tags: awk, gawk

This one cost me a night's sleep.

Suppose you have a file a_file.txt as follows.

```
1000    JUC_0000    1
2494    JUC_AAAA    2
2495    JUC_BBBB1   3
2495    JUC_BBBB2   4
4676    JUC_CCCC    5
4677    JUC_DDDD1   6
4677    JUC_DDDD2   7
```

If you run

```
awk '{if($1==4677){print $0;}}' a_file.txt
```

You get what you'd expect:

```
4677    JUC_DDDD1   6
4677    JUC_DDDD2   7
```

However, if you run

```
awk '{if($1==04677){print $0;}}' a_file.txt
```

you might be (I was) surprised to get

```
2495    JUC_BBBB1   3
2495    JUC_BBBB2   4
```

What appears to happen is that awk interprets 04677 as an octal representation of 2495 and runs with it.

Two questions:

1. Is my interpretation of the result correct?
2. Is there a way to prevent awk from interpreting numbers started with 0 as octal numbers and use their decimal interpretation instead?
3. Does gawk have the same behaviour and is it possible to change it?

Comment: `Is my interpretation of the result correct?` yes, your interpretation is correct

Comment: `(2)` Only I can think of `$1==int("04677")` ......

Comment: `Does gawk have the same behaviour` yes ... `is it possible to change it?` no idea

Comment: `(2) $1=="04677"`

Comment: Jose: Thanks. The int conversion should work.

Comment: James: That does not work as the column in a_file.txt does not contain the leading 0.

Comment: Given your comments below, you aren't actually executing the code you showed in your question and so this has nothing to do with octal vs decimal numbers. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42653696/1745001.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Numbers starting with a leading zero are `octal` numbers in `awk`. `2495` is the decimal value for the octal number `4677`.
2. There is no decimal number starting with `0` - except of `0` itself.
3. Yes and it won't change.

---

Btw, the ideomatic version of

```
awk '{if($1==4677){print $0;}}' file
```

is

```
awk '$1==4677' file
```

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest two alternatives, you can do a string match with quoting the key you're looking for, so "04677" won't match.

```
$ awk '$1=="04677"' file
```

Or, if you know that your key is numeric, you can add zero to convert to decimal

```
$ awk '$1==04677+0' file
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem arose from running awk within a script where the key 04677 was a string but the file had a numeric first column (no leading zeros). The "04677" option would not work, because the string on the file does not contain  the leading 0. I had thought this would not matter if I left it numeric, but the octal conversion caught me off guard. I believe the 04677+0 option would work well in this case.

Comment: @gvrocha that comment means your question doesn't represent your real problem and so we've all been trying to help you solve a problem you don't have. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42653696/1745001.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `$1==04677` instead of `$1==4677` you are **telling** awk to treat 04677 as an octal number, just like if you wrote `$1==0x4677` you'd be telling awk to treat it as hex and with `$1==4677""` you'd be telling awk to treat it as a string. If you don't want any of that then just don't do that.

**UPDATE:** wrt the comment you made under [@karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650444/1745001):

> The problem arose from running awk within a script where the key 04677
>   was a string but the file had a numeric first column (no leading
>   zeros). The "04677" option would not work, because the string on the
>   file does not contain the leading 0. I had thought this would not
>   matter if I left it numeric, but the octal conversion caught me off
>   guard. I believe the 04677+0 option would work well in this case.

What you just described in that comment is a **completely different problem** from what you stated in your question. Now you're no longer comparing a decimal to an octal you're comparing a number to a string and the operation used in that case is a string comparison (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Typing-and-Comparison) so `4677` != `"04677"` because the first character of `4677` is `"4"` while the first character of `04677` is `"0"`. It has nothing at all to do with the octal representation of the number. Yes using `"04677"+0` will work because that converts the string to a number (`4677`) and so you end up with a numeric, not string, comparison.